# How do I match a substring in either the first position or in the middle but with a specific character in front of it with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I might have a subject that looks like this `AAA12345678` or `BB-AAA1234`

And I want to match `AAA1234` either at the beginning of the subject or immediately following a dash.

I thought I could use `^|-AAA1234` but that doesn't want to work.

I'm new to regular expressions so any help would be great.

Comment: @Jack: because it is cheating!

Comment: But you do know something else: "at the beginning or with a specific character in front of it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the first part of the regex inside parentheses: `(^|-)AAA1234`.